# iconv() - How to determine the requires size for output buffer?

Tags: c++, c, utf-8

In my C++ code, I need to convert Unicode strings to UTF-8 strings using iconv(). Before calling the function, I need to allocate proper buffer size. A couple of examples I have seen overallocate the buffer (for example, two times the length of input string). I am wondering if there is a way to determine the exact size that would be required for the conversion. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you want to do two things:

1. Get the actual code point in each character (if "Unicode" means UTF-16, you need to handle surrogate pairs appropriately)
2. Determine how many bytes the code point will take up in UTF-8.

I'll assume that you have knowledge of how to do the first step and will focus on the second step:

- U+0000..U+007F = 1 byte
- U+0080..U+07FF = 2 bytes
- U+0800..U+FFFF = 3 bytes
- U+10000..U+1FFFFF = 4 bytes*
- U+200000..U+3FFFFFF = 5 bytes*
- U+4000000..U+7FFFFFFF = 6 bytes*

* UTF-8 can encode 2147483648 code points [0...0x7FFFFFFF], but UTF-16 can only encode the first 1114112 of them [0...0x10FFFF], which are the only ones currently designated. As a result, anything beyond U+10FFFF is pointless at the time of this writing. I included the others for completeness only.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I learned something new. My input is of wchar_t* type. This is UTF-16 on Windows but 4 bytes long on Linux. Out of 4 bytes, does U in your explanation refer to the first byte? Regards.

Comment: @Peter The _U+xxxx_ notation is simply the way Unicode code points are referred to. For example, U+12AB is code point 0x12AB. On Windows and possibly other systems such as IBM AIX where wchar_t is UTF-16, you'll want to handle surrogate pairs in the decoding. Since you're using wchar_t, which may not even be UTF-16 or UTF-32 on some platforms, you're probably better off letting a Unicode library such as ICU do the work. If you're only working with a particular set of platforms where you know the behavior of wchar_t, then by all means use iconv instead.